# empty_data ChoiceType returning null

Tags: symfony

I have a field called `defaultWarehouse` that is optional. I'm creating the form with the following code

```
class UserType extends AbstractType {
   ...
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
   {
      $builder->add('defaultWarehouse', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => $warehouses,
                'placeholder' => 'Choose warehouse',
                'required' => false,
                'empty_data' => '',
            ])

   }
}
```

The problem with that is whenever a user doesn't select a warehouse I have the following error:
`Expected argument of type "string", "NULL" given at property path "defaultWarehouse".` which leads me to believe that Symfony is converting an empty string to a `null` (which is obviously not the behavior to be expected).

I can confirm that the request has `defaultWarehouse => ''` when being sent back to the server via `POST`.

Any help would be highly appreciate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#empty-data

> Form data transformers will still be applied to the empty_data value.

In your example this is where null is returned:

https://github.com/symfony/form/blob/master/Extension/Core/DataTransformer/ChoiceToValueTransformer.php#L44

One way to solve the issue is to add a model transformer which would return an empty string instead of null.

```
    class UserType extends AbstractType {
    ...
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder->add('defaultWarehouse', ChoiceType::class, [
                'choices' => $warehouses,
                'placeholder' => 'Choose warehouse',
                'required' => false,
                'empty_data' => '',
            ]);

            $builder->get('defaultWarehouse')->addModelTransformer(
                new CallbackTransformer(
                    function ($value) {
                        return $value;
                    }, function ($value) {

                        if (null === $value) {
                            return '';
                        }

                        return $value;
                    }
                )
            );

        }
    }
```

Comment: +1 for solving my problem. +1 for providing link for the source of the problem and +1 for explaining it. Thank you sir. You solution worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

from the [`ChoiceType` docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#empty-data) (warning box at the end of that sub section):

> Form data transformers will still be applied to the `empty_data` value. This means that an empty string will be cast to `null`. Use a custom data transformer if you explicitly want to return the empty string.

one solution that *should* work is adding a choice "--- none ---" or something with value `''` (empty string). ... or you can add a custom data transformer as the warning suggests.